# JOOQ - map a single record using RecordMapper

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am not able to use a `RecordMapper mapper` to map a single record retrieved via fetchOne/fetchAny.

If I use for example (like in the manual)

```
List<Something> list =  create.selectFrom(TABLE).fetch().map(mapper);
```

it works,

but if i use the same mapper for:

```
Something pojo = create.selectFrom(TABLE).fetchOne().map(mapper);
```

it doesn't compile.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has to do with generics. While [`Result.map()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#map-org.jooq.RecordMapper-) takes a `RecordMapper<? super R,E>` argument type, [`Record.map()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#map-org.jooq.RecordMapper-) takes `RecordMapper<Record,E>`, because `Record` has no recursive generic type definition for `R`.

In other words, if you want to reuse the same mapper for both `Result.map()` and `Record.map()`, unfortunately, you will need to make it a `RecordMapper<Record, E>`, which means you'll lose some of the type safety on the record type.

A workaround would be to create a new result just for the sake of mapping:

```
Result<TableRecord> result = DSL.using(configuration).newResult(TABLE);
result.add(record);
Something pojo = result.map(mapper).get(0);
```

Comment: Maybe a method `Table#map(R record, RecordMapper<R, E> mapper)E` could be added

Comment: @gerferra: Hmm, that would be a rather unexpected location for this functionality. Besides, it wouldn't work for `Record1`, `Record2`, ...

Comment: Yes. I guess it only work with record types associated with tables. In the suggested method, `R` is the record type of the table.

Comment: Wdyt about `Something pojo = mapper.map(record);`?

Comment: Yes, I was proposing it as an alternative workaround.

Comment: @gerferra: You can provide an answer :)

Comment: :)  will do. I'm very new to jooq and was not sure if it was totally equivalent to the other workaround.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative workaround to the one provided by [Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25600490/63489) could be to use the mapper directly:

```
TableRecord record = create.selectFrom(TABLE).fetchOne();    
Something pojo = mapper.map(record);
```